# How to get innerHTML of some <span> tags inside a div onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write some javascript code that is supposed to auto complete a form (with 2 field: title and isbn) when the user click on a div.
That is an example of the div with class "search":

```
<div class='search'>
    <strong>Title: </strong>
    <span style='display:inline' id='title'>Harry Potter</span>
    <strong>ISBN:  </strong>
    <span id='isbn' style='display:inline'>9780545010221</span>
    <strong>Time:  </strong>
    <span id='time' style='display:inline'>22/11/2017 @ 19:00 </span>
</div>
```

I made a function to add an event handlers to the elements of the class "search":

```
function addEventHandlers() {
    var searchElement = document.getElementsByClassName("search");
    for (i = 0; i < searchElement.length; i++) {
        searchElement[i].addEventListener("click",compileForm);
    }
}
```

and a function to compile the form:

```
function compileForm(e) {
    if(e.target.id=='title') {
        document.getElementById("title").value=e.target.innerHTML;
    }
    else if (e.target.id=='isbn' && e.target.innerHTML!="--"){
        document.getElementById("isbn").value=e.target.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Sadly I wasn't able to do what I wanted so I had to settle with this alternative that works when the user clicks directly on the span element (one at a time).
Is there some way to get both title and isbn when I click on the div?

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: **Minor simplification:** You can put a single event listener on the `<div>`. It will get the event no matter which child was clicked on. Use `e.target` to indicate the element that was clicked on.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/nfd4n2xh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment made by Chris G I found the answer to my question.
The HTML code changed to this:

```
<div class='search'>
<strong>Title: </strong>
<span style='display:inline' class='title'>Harry Potter</span>
<strong>ISBN:  </strong>
<span class='isbn'>9780545010221</span>
<strong>Time:  </strong>
<span class='time'>22/11/2017 @ 19:00 </span>
</div>
```

and the javascript was changed as well:

```
function addEventHandlers() {
var searchElement = document.getElementsByClassName("search");
for (i = 0; i < searchElement.length; i++) {
  searchElement[i].addEventListener("click", compileForm);
}
}

function compileForm() {
  document.getElementById("title").value = this.querySelector(".title").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("isbn").value = this.querySelector(".isbn").innerHTML;
}
```